# how to enable visual effects in virtual box guest os

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox

I have linux mint 9 as guest os in virtual box. With windows 7 as host. Is it possible to enable the rich visual effects of linux mint 9 inside virtual box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to install the [VirtualBox Guest Additions](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-guest-addons.html)

Comment: You might also need to allocate more video memory to the virtual PC, possibly turn on 3d and or 2d video acceleration?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: no luck after installing guest additions, it still says that desktop effects could not be enabled

Comment: Did you enable 3D acceleration? How much memory have you given to the Video memory of the Guest OS? Make sure you are using the latest drivers for your graphics card. Enabling 3D acceleration often crashed my Ubuntu guest OS until I updated the video drivers to the latest version.

Comment: still no luck after enabling 3d acceleration. I even alloted the whole 128 mb of the built in video card.

Comment: If you're after Windows Aero, you need DirectX 9 support and a WDDM, which is only supported in vbox 4.1.0. "Windows guests: Experimental WDDM graphics driver, supporting Windows Aero (bug #4607) and providing Direct3D support using a cleaner approach (no need to install the guest drivers in Safe Mode anymore)" Make sure you update the Guest Addition as well.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, the procedure for both Ubuntu and Fedora is simply to:

1. Install Guest Additions
2. Make sure it has enough RAM
3. Enable 3D acceleration
4. Bump the video memory up to 32 MB (per something I read, I think on Fedora's website—I didn't try anything less, as that worked without bogging down OS X).

Presumably, this should work with Mint as well. I don't know if any extra setup is required on Windows.